# Engines principle overview

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, temperature, gas

In engines we have air and a hydrocarbon. Once we want to go forward we open the box containing it and the oxygen reacts with the hydrocarbon giving some gases. Due to the fact it is an exothermic reaction heat is released which heats up the gas and therfore the pressure of the gas is increased. And from that point it acts like a jetpack. Is my description correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on what you mean by "engine". An engine (as a general term) converts some form of energy into mechanical energy, but if you talk about a car motor the answer is no while for a rocket engine the answer is yes.

The reason is that in a car (as well as in a steam engine) the pressure from the gas moves a piston, which is then connected to the wheels, moving them. The same would be true for a boat, propeller airplane, or a submarine.

In a classic jet pack the engine is instead a rocket: the high pressure gas expands out through a nozzle, gaining high velocity and momentum, pushing the jet pack in the opposite direction (a "momentum machine"). Modern jet packs are apparently sometimes [turbojets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbojet), where the expanding gas powers a turbine connected to an air fan pumping in more air. This is still a momentum machine.

The key difference is whether the exhaust momentum is what accelerates the vehicle or if it provides force that moves it forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had had in mind the rocket engine before I posted this question.